# How to make organisation function more efficient

Tags: python, performance, loops

First of all this is not a high priority question as everything works and works just fine, however I can't shake the feeling that the code could be run a whole lot more efficiently if I weren't experiencing a major brain block.

Here is the gist: I am running a query from python to get a pile of entries from a database. Next I need to run through the entries and find the minimum value of a certain element, the maximum value, and then determine the values at 1/4, 1/2, and 3/4 between the two values. Finally I need to count how many entries fit within those categories.

```py
results = ({
   'min':999999,
   'min-value':0,
   'quarter':0,
   'quarter-value':0,
   'mid':0,
   'mid-value':0,
   'three-quarter':0,
   'max-value':0,
   'max':0
})

for query_value in q:
   results['min'] = min(query_value, results['min'])
   results['max'] = max(query_value, results['max'])

results['mid'] = (results['min']+results['max'])/2
results['quarter'] = (results['min']+results['mid'])/2
results['three-quarter'] = (results['mid']+results['max'])/2

for query_value in q:
   if query_value < results['quarter']:
      results['min-value'] += 1
   elif query_value < results['mid']:
      results['quarter-value'] += 1
   elif query_value < results['three-quarter']:
      results['mid-value'] += 1
   else:
      results['max-value'] += 1

return results
```

as you can see I am having to loop through the values twice which is a major red flag for me. I will continue working on it on my own. I have thought to run a second sql query of the database that requests the max and min values separately but will sql be more efficient at doing that than python? I'm just trying to get the runtime down a bit.

Any advice appreciated.

edit: I wanted to note that this is definitely a minimum representation of the code in question. Obviously the proper code includes tests to make sure elements aren't null and does have to do a decent bit more processing on the values acquired, however this is the core of the issue.

Comment: If it ***works*** (very important requirement) , this should probably go on [the Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: It looks good. It's `O(n)` complexity. It's not possible to avoid second iteration over the collection

Comment: what type is `q`? Could you use e.g. NumPy?

Comment: @Renat `O(n)` is good, BUT `O(n)` with a smaller constant is better ;-)

Comment: I think you should consider doing it at the DB level

Comment: @norok2 the type is `flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery`

Comment: Note that `'quarter-value'` is actually missing from `results` in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come to understand that `q` can be iterated through and that its result is essentially a number.
If the length of `q` is quite large you could be better off with the following:

```
import numpy as np

results = {}

hist, edges = np.histogram(q, 4)  # possibly: `q.all()` instead of `q`
results['min-value'], results['quarter-value'], results['mid-value'], results['max-value'] = hist
results['min'], results['quarter'], results['mid'], results['three-quarter'], results['max'] = edges
```

Also, you may want to consider using a bit more informative names for the keys of the array. For example, `min-value` would be quite misleading to me.

I would have much rather used, e.g.:

```
results['bin_1/4'], ... = hist
results['min'], results['1/4-val'], results['mid-val'], results['3/4-val'], results['max'] = edges
```

which, aside of being more explicit, can be easily automatized, e.g. and hence more easily extended, should the `n_bins` value change:

```
n_bins= 4
results.update({f'bin{i}/{n_bins}': x for i, x in enumerate(hist)})
```

---

Just to give you an idea about the numbers, check out these benchmark which show ~100x speed-up for the proposed approach (*blue* is your version, *orange* is mine; second row is a zoom on the fastest solution):

[image: bm_full]
[image: bm_fast]

Comment: This is fantastic. The version I put in the opening message is what is live atm but I will play with this and see if I can get it going for the next version update.